# Displaying only the first 6 children (JQuery)

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have this sample:

https://jsfiddle.net/trud4930/1/

This is code HTML:

```
<div class="parent">
<div class="parent2">
    <div class="child1"></div>        
    <div class="child1"></div>
    <div class="child1"></div>
    <div class="child1"></div>
    <div class="child1"></div>
    <div class="child1"></div>
    <div class="child1"></div>
    <div class="child1"></div>
    <div class="child1"></div>

</div>
```

This is code CSS:

```
    .child1
{
    width:50px;
    height:50px;
    background:blue;
    margin-top:10px;
}

.none{display:none;}
```

This is code JQuery:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

$(document).ready(function(){
    $( "parent2:lt(6)" ).css( "background:red" );
    var max=0;
    if(max<=6)
    {
        //   display:normal
    }else
    {
        //addClass .NONE
    }       


    });

});
```

What I wish is to display only the first 6 children and change the `background-color`

How can I solve this problem?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> ```
> display only the first 6 children and change the background-color
> ```

You need to use:

```
 $(".parent2 div").hide();
 $(".parent2 div:lt(6)").css("background","red").show();
```

**[Working Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/c465Lttk/)**

Answer (score 7):

Why use jQuery, when you can solve it with pure CSS:

```
.child1:nth-of-type(-n+6) { /* the first six */
    background: red;
}
.child1:nth-of-type(n+7) { /* all but the first six */
    display: none
}
```

[**Updated Fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/trud4930/3/)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to select them dynamically in jQuery you can use the slice() method. Here is an example (just put a display:none in the toggled class to hide them):

```js
$('button').on('click', function() {
  $('.child').slice(0, 6).toggleClass('toggled');
});
```

```css
.toggled {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child">lorem</div>
  <div class="child">lorem</div>
  <div class="child">lorem</div>
  <div class="child">lorem</div>
  <div class="child">lorem</div>
  <div class="child">lorem</div>
  <div class="child">lorem</div>
  <div class="child">lorem</div>
  <div class="child">lorem</div>
</div>
<button>Change first 6</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this also doing what you need; (I prefer @LinkinTed's answer though)

```
    $( ".parent" ).find("div[class^=child]:lt(6)").css( "background","red" );
    $( ".parent" ).find("div[class^=child]:gt(5)").addClass( "none" );
```

https://jsfiddle.net/trud4930/6/